# How can I move my dark/light mode logic to my context file?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, darkmode

So I am using React Context to store all my state logic for my application. The one thing I haven't been able to transfer over is my light/dark mode code and I am wondering how I can transfer it to my context file.

```
const [lightMode, setLightMode] = useState(false);

  //Call from local Storage
  useEffect(() => {
    const storedPreference = localStorage.getItem('prefersLightMode');
    try {
      if (storedPreference) {
        setLightMode(JSON.parse(storedPreference));
      } else {
        const prefersLightMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches;
        setLightMode(prefersLightMode);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  //Set to Local Storage
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (lightMode) {
        localStorage.setItem('prefersLightMode', 'true');
        document.body.classList.add('light');
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('prefersLightMode', 'false');
        document.body.classList.remove('light');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, [lightMode]);
```

This is my toggle to switch between dark/light mode. An onChange toggles everything.

```
         <div className="form-control">
              <label className="label cursor-pointer">
                <span className="label-text">Remember me</span>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  className="toggle toggle-primary"
                  onChange={() => {
                    setLightMode(!lightMode);
                  }}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
```

When I move everything to context I keep getting an error that saying 'setLightMode is not a function at onChange' when I try to attach setLightMode to the onChange.

Comment: Are you returning `lightMode` and `setLightMode` in your context and how are you using your context in the component?

Comment: From the context file I am sending back lightMode and setLightMode. In the component I am just calling it like this const {lightMode, setLightMode} = useContext(AppContext). Apologies if this isn't clear. I  would show you a code snippet but I shut off my computer for the night. I can attach a proper snippet when I wake up.

Comment: Ok from your comment your code looks fine to me. But a proper code snipped would definitely help.